# How do i execute some line in a file as a command in ternimal?

Tags: linux, command

I write down some commands row by row in a file, and I want to execute the commands through grep and pipe;

for example:
1.there is a file a.txt,which content is like below:

```
echo "hello world"
ls -l
```

2.then I want execute the first line in my terminal, so I want it like this:

```
cat a.txt | grep echo | execute the output of previous commands
```

so that, I can finally execute the command, which is the first line of a.txt.
(can not find any answer of this, so I come here to find some help.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either pipe the command to bash (or any other shell) to execute it:

```
sed -n 1p a.txt | bash
```

or you can use `eval` with command substitution:

```
eval $(head -n1 a.txt)
```

BTW, I showed you another two ways how to extract the line from the file.